# how to echo Drop down value from data base in edit page

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to echo database value for the drop down in edit mode. but in edit page it doesn't show the previously selected drop down value. now i want to echo database values to the drop down. how can i do it. My view controller and model are below. Please any one can help me.

View

```
<!--//Address--> 
<tr><td><?php echo '<label for="heading" class="col-sm-0 control-label">Address </label>';?></td>
    <td class="col-lg-10">
<?php
$data = array(
          'name'        => 'address',
          'value'          => $post->address,
          'class'       => 'form-control',
          'style'       => 'width:140%',
          'placeholder' => 'Address of Your Site'
        );
echo form_input($data);
echo '<br>';
?>
        </td>
</tr>       
<!--//Address-->

    <?php foreach ($single as $post):?>
        $attributes = 'class = "form-control" id = "client" style="width:140%; height:35px;"';
        $buildings = array('-SELECT-'=>'-SELECT-', 'House'=>'House', 'Building Complex'=>'Building Complex', 'Commercial Building'=>'Commercial Building', 'Hotel'=>'Hotel','Hospital'=>'Hospital' );
        echo form_dropdown('building', $buildings, $post->building,set_value('building'), $attributes);
    ?>
```

Controller

```
function edit_single(){
$id = $this->uri->segment(3);
//load project details according to relevent id
$data['single'] = $this->project_registration_details->show_pro_id($id); 
$this->load->view('client/project_registration_edit_view',$data);
}
```

Model

```
function show_pro_id($id){
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('project_registration');
$this->db->join('client', 'client.client_id = project_registration.reg_client_id');
$this->db->where('project_registration.id',$id);
$query = $this->db->get();
$result = $query->result();
return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
set_value('building',$post->building)
```

in your selected part of `form_dropdown` function.

Try..

```
echo form_dropdown('building', $buildings,set_value('building',$post->building), $attributes);
```

**Updated Answer**

```
<?php foreach($single as $post) { ?>
    <select name="building" class = "form-control" id = "client" style="width:140%; height:35px;">
        <?php 
        $buildings = array('-SELECT-'=>'-SELECT-', 'House'=>'House', 'Building Complex'=>'Building Complex', 'Commercial Building'=>'Commercial Building', 'Hotel'=>'Hotel','Hospital'=>'Hospital' );
        foreach($buildings as $key => $building) { ?>
             <option value="<?php echo $key; ?>" <?php echo set_select('building', $post->building); ?>><?php echo $building; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: what is the value of `$post->building` ?

Comment: house  is the value in database table

Comment: No, not the value in table... i mean the value in `$post->building` variable

Comment: this is used to retrive values in "building" column in table

Comment: Please provide more code to know that what value is stored in `$single` variable.

Comment: print_r($result) before return in model and check the data is fetching properly.

Comment: I missed `set_select('building', $post->building);`.

Comment: not working yet. is there any another method to that

Comment: No other methods.. The methods are right.. I think the issue in your value fetching from database.

Comment: when i echo $post->building it will print the value